# I started a Django project with all requirements but static files can't load successfully

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm working with Python 3.8.3, pip 20.1.1, Django 3.0.6 and virtual environment are already installed but I'm not getting the style from my CSS files and
the web page behavior from JavaScript onto my web page and here is the photo of errors in my console

---

[image: Error from console]

---

In my settings I configured well all about the static file and the template and the following is my

**settings.py**

```
STATICFILES = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

and that's also the the URLs for the whole projects

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('estate_web.urls'))
]
```

and I done well all about the URL configuration and the following is my app URL

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```

and that's the views which return the page

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I don't know if there is any error in my codes but I can't get the website as I expected and I want to know if there is any fixation of this because I met with it couple times.

Comment: Did you run `manage.py collectstatic`? Are you running with or without `DEBUG = True`? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Did you setup `STATIC_URL`? See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: of course i collect the static files and the DEBUG = True

Comment: yes check at my settings.py

Comment: Are you loading statics in your html template? Ensure `{% load static %}` is added at the top of the template file.

Comment: of course i loaded it and if i did't i would seen different error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do it for your debug server, you can add this lines to your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
...
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
              static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: but to do this require to set `DEBUG = False` now it worked